# Edit the list item by click on any custom column

Tags: infopath

I have a custom list. The list has 5 columns:

```
A B C D E
```

These column is taking value from am InfoPath form.
I want to know any way to edit the items by click on any value on the row?

Eg.

```
Column Name:   A   B  C  D E
Value      :   10 20 30 40 50
```

If I click on `30`, the item should be open in editable form.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the view in SharePoint Designer and change the display of the values ​​on the links to edit forms with additional query parameters that stores the value of the column.